# org-mode report with start and end time for each day of the week

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

I'm starting to use (a total newbie, actually) org-mode clocking commands to track time spent during the job day.

I need to fill some reports on daily start and end time of my work day.  This is just: I sat to code at 9am and left at 1pm.  For each week's day.

I've been reading through the docs and I can just find reports based on the task items and don't see how to accomplish my report.

Where can I start to look at or what docs would you recommend?

Thanks.